# Find difference between two timestamps - iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, unix-timestamp, nstimeinterval, difference

I am trying to use NSTimeInterval to figure out the difference between two timestamps in my iOS application. However I when trying to pass in my timestamp, I get the following error:

> Bad receiver type 'double'

Here is my code:

```
// Get the current date/time in timestamp format.
NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970]];
double current = [timestamp doubleValue];

// Find difference between current timestamp and
// the timestamp returned in the JSON file.
NSTimeInterval difference = [current timeIntervalSinceDate:1296748524];
```

I thought that NSTimeInterval is just a another meaning for double.. is it not?

Note that '1296748524' is just being used here as a test.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for you're time :)

Comment: Why are you converting to a string to do the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recognize that timestamp!  If you're going to get a timestamp as a string, and then convert it back to a double, you can just get it as a double.

Fix:

```
NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970]];
double current = [timestamp doubleValue];
NSTimeInterval difference = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:current] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1296748524]];

NSLog(@"difference: %f", difference);
```

Better:

```
double currentt = [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval differ= [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:currentt] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1296748524]];
NSLog(@"differ: %f", differ);
```

But what you're really doing is converting a date to a timestamp to a string to a timestamp to a date to a timestamp, so why not just use that from the beginning and use:

Best:

```
double timeStampFromJSON = 1296748524; // or whatever from your JSON
double dif = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - timeStampFromJSON;
NSLog(@"dif: %f", dif);
```

All will be same result.

Comment: I disagree that this is "best". First of all "[NSDate new]", which functional, is not the dominant idiom; "[NSDate date]" or "[[NSDate alloc] init]" are. Second, I believe your "best" code would be extremely difficult to figure out 6 months later.

Comment: I agree with you on the date, and I updated, but I can't imagine it ever being difficult to figure out.  You are just getting the interval of the current date. Every other function does the same thing but adds unnecessary steps. It's a pretty basic line of code, and every other method has blatant redundancies.

Comment: also [[NSDate alloc]init] is pretty much the same as [NSDate new]

Comment: Well, are you actually hard-coding that value? You said you recognized it, so maybe it's a reference date, but I don't recognize it. Without comments or more standard Objective-C, this code isn't friendly to another developer. Also, "new" is implemented on `NSObject` to call `alloc] init]` (meaning it's exactly the same), but it still isn't standard coding practice. I'm not saying the code isn't functional, but if I were working on code and saw this, it would be a frustrating discovery.

Comment: I'm not hardcoding it, it's the value provided in the question.  I'm assuming it has some significance to them, and I assume that if it's something they need to remember, they'll assign it a variable.

Comment: And I agree that your "best" is now best!

Comment: All is well in the kingdom!

Comment: "All bow before the mighty Logan!" ;-)

Comment: @Logan But how do I display this difference in days? The difference timestamp when converted using a simple epoch converter just changes into a date... How do I change it into days? I want the difference in days.

Comment: The difference is in seconds, a day is 60 * 60 * 24 seconds (seconds, minutes, hours)  Take your difference and divide by the day value, that's how many days difference it is.

Answer (score 2):

`timeIntervalSinceDate:` expects to receive an `NSDate`. Also, it is an instance method for an `NSDate`. Yes, the return value is, essentially, a `double`, but it's a function using `NSDate` objects.

Here's an example of appropriate usage:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate ... // some way to get a valid NSDate
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate ... // some way to get a valid NSDate

NSTimeInterval elapsed = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
```

In the above example, "elapsed" will contain the number of seconds that have elapsed between "date1" and "date2". If "date1" is prior to "date2", the value will be negative.